# when using selenium with phantomJS, I got a WinError 87.

Tags: selenium, phantomjs

I have selenium 3.6.0 and phantomjs-2.1.1-windows in my Windows 10,and set the PATH to the phantomJS.exe. When I use the code below:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='')
```

I got the fault:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Python 3.5.4\test\BeautifulSoup.py", line 10, in <module>
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='')
File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-
packages\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\webdriver.py", line 52, in __init__
self.service.start()
File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-
packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 74, in start
stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 676, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 957, in 
_execute_child
startupinfo)
OSError: [WinError 87] wrong parameters。
```

Comment: Hi, it would help a lot if you could ask a question to get an answer to. This question reads like an answer to another question - "What happens when passing wrong parameters to `webdriver.PhantomJS()`?". Clarify what you need help with, please.

Comment: Sorry, I just want to run through the code. And I know what happens now. Thank you!

Comment: Not a problem, I am glad that you found what you needed to know :) I tried to convey that questions asked how you asked yours - like providing an answer to a different question - usually does not receive a good answer. Maybe I worded it wrong to convey that message, sorry if I sounded overly harsh. Your own answer does indeed answer what I think your question meant (which was "why am I getting this error?").

Comment: Thanks for your concern.:)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for disturbing. Actually when I set the phantomJS.exe to the $PATH. I actually do not need any argument in the webdriver.PhantomJS(). I found the doc below:
    executable_path - path to the executable. If the default is used it assumes the executable is in the $PATH